# Disable bootstrap select according to another select element

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two select elements enhanced with bootstrap select. When a value is set on one of the select elements the other needs to be disabled.

These are my two select elements:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-1" name="select-1" data-live-search-placeholder="Search..." data-live-search="true" style="font-family:Open Sans, FontAwesome">
    <option data-tokens="disabled" value="" data-hidden="true" data-icon="fa fa-location-arrow">Element 1</option>
        <?php foreach ( $items as $item ) { ?>
            <option data-tokens="<?= $item['value']; ?>"><?= $item['value']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select><br>
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-2" name="select-2" data-live-search-placeholder="Search..." data-live-search="true" style="font-family:Open Sans, FontAwesome">
    <option data-tokens="disabled" value="" data-hidden="true" data-icon="fa fa-calendar">Element 2</option>
        <?php foreach ( $moreItems as $item ) { ?>
            <option data-tokens="<?= $item['value'] ?>"><?= $item['label'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

What have I've come up with so far:

```
jQuery("select").change(function() {
    if(????){
       jQuery(this).prop("disabled")
    }
});
```

And

```
jQuery( 'select' ).prop( 'disabled','disabled' ).selectpicker( 'refresh' );
```

Comment: In your first example it looks like you are about to disable the element that you used to select something with. That contradicts the requirement that the other element should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('select:not(.active)').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<select class="form-control">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>


<select class="form-control">
  <option value="11">7</option>
  <option value="21">8</option>
  <option value="31">9</option>
  <option value="41">10</option>
  <option value="51">11</option>
  <option value="61">12</option>
</select>
```

Simple, use can use a simple class to indicate what select is active like this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('select:not(.active)').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

**Or**, disable the `<select>` tags who doesn't have value:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('select:').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()) $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will work for normal select elements, but not for the bootstrap select element... Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls

Comment: In JQuery is all the same, Bootstrap only apply Style on the elements .. Give it a try...

Comment: See my Edit @FrankGroot

Comment: @MatheusCuba To clarify; "Bootstrap Select" is a jQuery plugin that completely replaces the `<select>` element; it is not part of Bootstrap's framework or related to BS4s `.custom-select` styles.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close in getting that to work.

Most important thing you were missing is **separate IDs** for the select elements.

Here's a code snippet with the ID fix and pretty much doing similar to what you were trying on i.e.

1. Adding disabled `prop` to the select element.
2. Calling `.selectpicker('refresh')`
3. Added a condition based on which the above 2 are called (check out the comments in the code)

```js
$('select.selectpicker').selectpicker().on('change', function () {

 // select the <select> to be disabled
 var countrySelect = $('select#select-1');
  
 // add disabled property based on some condition and refresh the selectpicker
 countrySelect.prop('disabled', $(this).val() === '2');
  countrySelect.selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-1" name="select-1" data-live-search-placeholder="Search..." data-live-search="true" style="font-family:Open Sans, FontAwesome">
    <option data-tokens="disabled" value="" data-hidden="true" data-icon="fa fa-location-arrow">Element 1</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   
</select><br>
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-2" name="select-2" data-live-search-placeholder="Search..." data-live-search="true" style="font-family:Open Sans, FontAwesome">
    <option data-tokens="disabled" value="" data-hidden="true" data-icon="fa fa-calendar">Element 2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Looks like you're disabling the original element instead of the required element.

Comment: Oh is it? (I can't re-check after your edits) I was disabling the second select based on first's output (`countrySelect` was selecting the second one). I didn't double check I guess, my bad. Anyway, thanks for correcting and seems like Frank got to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the second select element to be disabled when a certain option is selected in the first element.

I've used [Shashank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995718/540812) a bit but modified it to perform as you requested:

```js
var select1 = jQuery('#select-1'),
  select2 = jQuery('#select-2');

select1.selectpicker().on('change', function () {
  select2.prop('disabled', $(this).val() === '2').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-1" name="select-1" data-live-search-placeholder="Search..." data-live-search="true" style="font-family:Open Sans, FontAwesome">
    <option data-tokens="disabled" value="" data-hidden="true" data-icon="fa fa-location-arrow">Element 1</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   
</select><br>
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-2" name="select-2" data-live-search-placeholder="Search..." data-live-search="true" style="font-family:Open Sans, FontAwesome">
    <option data-tokens="disabled" value="" data-hidden="true" data-icon="fa fa-calendar">Element 2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help @Shashank and @halfpastfour.am with your answers i came to the following solution.

```js
var select1 = jQuery('#select-1'),
  select2 = jQuery('#select-2');

select1.selectpicker().on('change', function () {
  select2.prop('disabled', $(this).val() != '').selectpicker('refresh');
});

select2.selectpicker().on('change', function () {
  select1.prop('disabled', $(this).val() != '').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-1" name="select-1" data-live-search-placeholder="Search..." data-live-search="true" style="font-family:Open Sans, FontAwesome">
    <option data-tokens="disabled" value="" data-hidden="true" data-icon="fa fa-location-arrow">Element 1</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   
</select><br>
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-2" name="select-2" data-live-search-placeholder="Search..." data-live-search="true" style="font-family:Open Sans, FontAwesome">
    <option data-tokens="disabled" value="" data-hidden="true" data-icon="fa fa-calendar">Element 2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```